# Reboot check is showing all reboots not just last

Tags: powershell, reboot

I have a reboot check script that is run post MW, I need it to pull just the last reboot to verify the servers have been rebooted, currently they pull all reboot history. Below is my script:

```
$DHCP = (Get-Content -Path "\\termserv\d$\SERVER1\SERVER2\Scripts\morescripts\DHCPServers.txt")

foreach ($Server in $DHCP) {
    Get-Service -ComputerName $Server -DisplayName "DHCP Server" |
        ConvertTo-Html -Title "PScomputername" -Body "<H3> SERVER2 Uptime Report </H3> " -Property PSComputername >> \\termserv\d$\SERVER1\SERVER2\Server3\SERVER2.html
    Get-Service -ComputerName $Server -DisplayName "DHCP Server" |
        ConvertTo-Html -Property MachineName,Status,ServiceName | 
        foreach {
            if ($_ -like "*<td>Running</td>*") {
                $_ -replace "<tr>", "<tr bgcolor=green>"
            } elseif ($_ -like "*<td>Stopped</td>*") {
                $_ -replace "<tr>", "<tr bgcolor=red>"
            } else {
                $_
            }
        } >> \\termserv\d$\SERVER1\SERVER2\Server3\SERVER2.html
    Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $Server | 
        Select PSComputername, @{n='BootTime';e={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastBootupTime)}} |
        ConvertTo-Html -Property PSComputerName,BootTime >> \\termserv\d$\SERVER1\SERVER2\Server3\SERVER2.html
    ConvertTo-Html -Property PSComputerName,Installedon,Description,caption >> \\termserv\d$\SERVER1\SERVER2\Server3\SERVER2.html
}


$Print = (Get-Content -Path "\\termserv\d$\SERVER1\SERVER2\Scripts\morescripts\PrintServers.txt")

foreach ($Server in $Print) {
    Get-Service -ComputerName $Server -DisplayName "Print Spooler" |
        ConvertTo-Html -Property MachineName,Status,ServiceName | 
        foreach {
            if ($_ -like "*<td>Running</td>*") {
                $_ -replace "<tr>", "<tr bgcolor=green>"
            } elseif ($_ -like "*<td>Stopped</td>*") {
                $_ -replace "<tr>", "<tr bgcolor=red>"
            } else {
                $_
            }
        } >> \\termserv\d$\SERVER1\SERVER2\Server3\SERVER2.html
    Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $Server | 
        Select PSComputername, @{n='BootTime';e={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastBootupTime)}} | 
        ConvertTo-Html -Property PSComputerName,BootTime >> \\termserv\d$\SERVER1\SERVER2\Server3\SERVER2.html
    ConvertTo-Html -Property PSComputerName,Installedon,Description,caption >> \\termserv\d$\SERVER1\SERVER2\Server3\SERVER2.html
}
```

Comment: I've reformatted as best I could for better legibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to `Sort-Object` with a calculated property and then tell `Select-Object` to pick the first item:

```
Get-WmiObject -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Server |
    Sort-Object -Property @{e={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastBootupTime)}} -Descending |
    Select-Object -First 1 -Property [...] |
    ConvertTo-Html [...]
```

It should be noted that the final `ConvertTo-Html` call in each main `foreach` loop doesn't have anything to convert as far as I can tell.  They're going to create an empty HTML document with an empty table and append that to your file.

Also, you're appending multiple HTML documents to the `server2.html` file.  If they're going to be in the same document, you should start the entire file with `<html><head><title /></head><body>`, then use the `-Fragment` parameter on all of your `ConvertTo-Html` calls, and finally close the document with  `</body></html>`.  Your current method may work, but you're generating an explicitly invalid HTML document.  A browser that renders correctly should only display the first table.

Comment: Thanks Bacon, I modified it a little and it worked great you win the green check